# Multiple DCSliders sending different control values (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, slider

This question may be very specific, but I'm new to all this and really need some help.

I'm building an iPhone synth app.
I am using DCSliders an DCKnobs (they look nicer than the standard UISliders).

https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCControls#readme

I am also working with libpd (a Pure Data library) so the audio DSP is handled by an embedded Pure Data patch.

https://gitorious.org/pdlib

I have got multiple DCSliders and DCKnobs in my interface. I am able to send control values from the sliders/knobs to Pure Data by making a class the delegate of the DCSlider...

```
- (void)loadView {
  [super loadView];
  self.mySlider = [[[DCSlider alloc] initWithDelegate:self] autorelease];
  self.mySlider.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 20.0, 120.0);

  [self.view addSubview:self.mySlider];
}
```

Then I implement a method to send control values to a receiver in Pure Data...

```
- (void)controlValueDidChange:(float)value sender:(id)sender {  
    [PdBase sendFloat:value toReceiver:@"beatvol"];
}
```

This all works ok.

The problem is that all of the sliders are sending the same control values.

How do I get each of the DCSliders to send independent control values to different receivers in Pure Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a **tag** to your sliders. Then in `controlValueDidChange:` you need to get that tag and do your actions according to the tags:

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    [super loadView];
    mySlider = [[[DCSlider alloc] initWithDelegate:self] autorelease];
    mySlider.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 20.0, 120.0);
    mySlider.tag = 0;
    [self.view addSubview: mySlider];
}
- (void)controlValueDidChange:(float)value sender:(id)sender 
{  
    DCSlider * slider = (DCSlider *)sender;

    switch (slider.tag) 
    {
        case 0: 
        { 
            [PdBase sendFloat:value toReceiver:@"beatvol"];
        }
            break;
        case 1: 
        { 
            /*  do something for the 2nd slider  */;
        }
            break;
    }        
}
```

Comment: For the second slider (mySlider2) I put
self.mySlider2.tag = 1

Comment: then in case 1:
[PdBase sendFloat:value toReceiver:@"bassvol"];

Comment: Thanks for your help though. I must have done something wrong.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong because this should work. It's what I use in a lot of my code.

Comment: also, try removing **`self.`**

Comment: Removing self did work. Thanks. 
But now the sliders are sending the wrong control values. Slider 1 is sending control values to "bassvol" and Slider 2 is sending control values to "beatvol". I don't know why they are the wrong way around?

Comment: `- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 
 slider.tag = 0;
 slider = [[[DCSlider alloc] initWithDelegate:self] autorelease];
 slider.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,100);
 [self.sliderContainer addSubview:slider]; 
 
 slider2.tag = 1; 
 slider2 = [[[DCSlider alloc] initWithDelegate:self] autorelease];
 slider2.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,100);
 [self.sliderContainer2 addSubview:slider2]; 
}`

Comment: `- (void)controlValueDidChange:(float)value sender:(id)sender {  
 
 DCSlider * slidertag = (DCSlider *)sender;
 
    switch (slidertag.tag) 
    {
        case 0: 
        { 
            [PdBase sendFloat:value toReceiver:@"beatvol"];
        }
            break;
        case 1: 
        { 
            [PdBase sendFloat:value toReceiver:@"bassvol"];
        }
            break;
    }        
}`