# Only 1 case is working in switch statement (Objective C)

Tags: xcode, audio, tags, slider, switch-statement

I am working in Xcode on a synthesizer application. I am using custom sliders and knobs. I want these to send control values to receivers in an embedded Pure Data patch (I am using libpd as a Pure Data library and wrapper).

I have multiple custom sliders and knobs on my interface. I want each one to send only their own control values independently of the other sliders/knobs.

I am using tags and a switch statement.
The problem is that only the first case is working and all of the sliders and knobs are sending control values to the same receiver.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

// Slider 1

    slider.tag = 0;
    slider = [[[DCSlider alloc] initWithDelegate:self] autorelease];
    slider.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,100);
    [self.sliderContainer addSubview: slider];


// Slider 2 

    slider2.tag = 1;    
    slider2 = [[[DCSlider alloc] initWithDelegate:self] autorelease];
    slider2.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,100); 
    [self.sliderContainer2 addSubview: slider2];    
}
```

and then I implement the method here...

```
- (void)controlValueDidChange:(float)value sender:(id)sender { 

    DCSlider *slidertag = (DCSlider *)sender;

    switch (slidertag.tag) 
    {
        case 0: 
        { 
            [PdBase sendFloat:value toReceiver:@"beatvol"];
        }
            break;
        case 1: 
        { 
            [PdBase sendFloat:value toReceiver:@"bassvol"];
        }
            break;
    }     
}
```

Can anyone help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geez, still at it?

You obviously need to assign a separate target for each slider!

Also, in your example, you assign the tag before you create the slider, no good. You should always place your `init` before setting any properties.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Slider 1

    slider = [[[DCSlider alloc] initWithDelegate:self] autorelease];
    slider.tag = 0;
    slider.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,100);
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(controlBassValueDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.sliderContainer addSubview: slider];

    // Slider 2 

    slider2 = [[[DCSlider alloc] initWithDelegate:self] autorelease];
    slider2.tag = 1;
    slider2.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,100); 
    [slider2 addTarget:self action:@selector(controlBeatValueDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.sliderContainer2 addSubview: slider2];    
}

- (void)controlBassValueDidChange:(float)value sender:(id)sender 
{ 
    [PdBase sendFloat:value toReceiver:@"bassvol"];
}
- (void)controlBeatValueDidChange:(float)value sender:(id)sender 
{ 
    [PdBase sendFloat:value toReceiver:@"beatvol"];
}
```

And if you are going to use [**my answer to your other question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869168/multiple-dcsliders-sending-different-control-values-xcode/6869217#6869217), the least you could do is give it an upvote. ;—]

Comment: @ WrightsCS: an upvote? I think I've done that now. I marked the last post as useful. I really do appreciate all the help and advice you (and everyone else is offering me).

Comment: @ WrightsCS: That worked!!!! It wasn't working because, like you said, I assigned the tag before I created the slider.
You are a top geezer! Thank you very much.
How do I give you big thumbs up on this site?

Comment: tick the checkmark and the UP arrow .. same for other question as well!

Comment: apparently I need to earn more reputation to select the UP arrow. once I've earned that rep I'll make sure I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-check your switch syntax [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Objective-C_switch_Statement).  Basically, you should lose the inner delimiters.